How do I find files with ampersands in their names in Linux
I would have thought
ls \*\&\*

would work but it doesn't.

Or ls *"&"* (quoting)

All done; I'll remove my comment.

When you write ls \*\&\*, you are escaping the wildcard characters (*) so that they are interpreted literally, rather than as wildcards. You are looking for a file with the literal name *&*.
To list files in the current directory containing &, you would write instead:
ls *\&*

(or ls *"&"* or ls *'&'*, etc). This way you are escaping only the & character and the * characters continue to have their special meaning.

I'm so used to escaping that I over-escaped!   Thank you.
